# Locating a Dynamic li element with changing number using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am new selenium and python and just started two days back.Im doing a web scraping and trying to locate a dynamic li tage with changing number

I have located the xpaths using Chrome Dev Tools. However Since its a  dynamic element i figured part of it .

I know I could use a for loop with incrementing variable for li tag but then I wanted to know if there any other ways to achieve it.There is function for endswith in XML but its XML2.0 and browsers support version 1

Im trying something like this and

```
  //*[contains(@id,"submenu1")]/li[i]/a/span
```

How do i structure the last elements of above xpath(/li[i]/a/span) so that it can capture dynamic number values as posted above?

Here is the HTML code of elements

```
 //*[@id="submenu1"]/li[1]/a/span
 //*[@id="submenu1"]/li[2]/a/span
 //*[@id="submenu1"]/li[3]/a/span
 //*[@id="submenu1"]/li[4]/a/span
 //*[@id="submenu1"]/li[5]/a/span
 //*[@id="submenu1"]/li[6]/a/span
 //*[@id="submenu1"]/li[7]/a/span
```

The actual should be able to capture with changing number inside li tag

Comment: Do you want to capture last element?

Comment: No I want to capture all the elements starting from 1 to 7

Comment: you can use the xpath `//*[@id="submenu1"]/li/a/span` with `find_elements_by_xpath`. so you will get all elements and loop thru. no need to worry about last element.

Comment: I dont need to just derive them. I need to click on each element. Doing this will make it a string i think so selnium will say not interactable error

Comment: then you need to re-identify/locate it each time in loop.

Comment: Yeah I agree. But using a for loop would make it a string making it unrecognizing to Selenium if im right?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Okay Give me some time.Be right back

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact there is no built-in [ends-with](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with) function in [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) there are existing [XPath functions and operators](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) which allow you to implement this, example HTML:

```
<a href="http://com.example">com.example</a>
<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
```

Example XPath which locates the link which ends with `com`:

```
//a[substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('com')+ 1, string-length(text()))= 'com']
```

Demo:

[image]